# Invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference verifying jwt expiration time

Tags: go, jwt

I'm working on a login with golang using jwt token, everything so far is god, it checks what time is left on the token, if there is no token it send a message
But I have 2 problems, if the token is invalid or the expiration time is out it shows this error:

[image]

And the line that carry the error is this
`claims := token.Claims.(*jwtCustomClaims)`

my jwtCustomClaims variable is this:

```
type jwtCustomClaims struct {
    User     string `json:"email"`
    Nombre   string `json:"nombre"`
    Apellido string `json:"apellido"`
    Edad     int    `json:"edad"`
    Genero   string `json:"genero"`
    Rol      string `json:"rol"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}
```

with this struct is also generated the token, and the full function to check the token is this

```
func ValidateToken(tokenString string, secretKey string, c *fiber.Ctx) (*jwt.Token, error) {
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &jwtCustomClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(secretKey), nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        if err == jwt.ErrSignatureInvalid {
            return nil, err
        }
        return nil, c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "Unauthorized",
            "code":    400,
        })

    }

    _, ok := token.Claims.(*jwtCustomClaims)
    if !ok || !token.Valid {
        return nil, c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "Unauthorized",
            "code":    400,
        })
    }

    return token, nil
}

func TokenMiddleware(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    tokenString := c.Get("Authorization")
    if tokenString == "" {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "No token",
            "code":    400,
        })
    }

    // Separa el token del encabezado "Bearer"
    tokenString = strings.ReplaceAll(tokenString, "Bearer ", "")

    token, err := ValidateToken(tokenString, os.Getenv("SECRET"), c)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

        claims := token.Claims.(*jwtCustomClaims)

        expiresIn := time.Until(time.Unix(claims.ExpiresAt, 0))
        if expiresIn > 0 {
            return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
                "message":    "Token is valid",
                "expires_in": expiresIn.String(),
                "is_expired": false,
            })
            //return c.Next()
        } else {
            return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
                "message":    "Token is valid but expired",
                "expires_in": 0,
                "is_expired": true,
            })
        }
}
```

To check if it validate the token i just try to put another type of token, from an other proyect and write it wrong just to test but it send a console error. And for the expiration time i look the error on the web and a solution to this is to write it like this `if claims == nil` but it didn't work, I don't know what else to do

Comment: is `token` nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test it:

```
func ValidateToken(tokenString string, secretKey string, c *fiber.Ctx) (jwtCustomClaims, error) {
    var claims jwtCustomClaims
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(secretKey), nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        if err == jwt.ErrSignatureInvalid {
            return jwtCustomClaims{}, err
        }
        return jwtCustomClaims{}, c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "Unauthorized",
            "code":    400,
        })

    }

    if !token.Valid {
        return jwtCustomClaims{}, c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "Unauthorized",
            "code":    400,
        })
    }

    return claims, nil
}

func TokenMiddleware(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    .
    .
    .

    claims, err := ValidateToken(tokenString, os.Getenv("SECRET"), c)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    expiresIn := time.Until(time.Unix(claims.ExpiresAt, 0))

    .
    .
    .
}
```